# Folding data in R for k fold cross validation based on a condition

Tags: r, validation, fold

I am working on resource selection of black-tailed deer using a random effect model as below:

```
  suma<-read.csv("sum_active.csv", header=TRUE) 
suma$bps1<-as.factor(suma$bps)
suma$sclass1<-as.factor( suma$sclass1)
suma$sclass2<-as.factor( suma$sclass2)
suma$sclass3<-as.factor( suma$sclass3)
suma$sclass4<-as.factor( suma$sclass4)
suma$sclass5<-as.factor( suma$sclass5)
suma$sclass6<-as.factor( suma$sclass6)


stdsuma<- suma
stdsuma$cc <- scale(stdsuma$cc)
stdsuma$edgedensi <- scale(stdsuma$edgedensi)
stdsuma$dem <- scale(stdsuma$dem)
stdsuma$dist <- scale(stdsuma$dist)
stdsuma$waterdst <- scale(stdsuma$waterdst)
stdsuma$vrm <- scale(stdsuma$vrm)
stdsuma$slp <- scale(stdsuma$slp)
stdsuma$sin <- scale(stdsuma$sin)
stdsuma$cos <- scale(stdsuma$cos)
stdsuma$july <- scale(stdsuma$july)

sumaf1<-glmer( UA ~ dem+cos+sin+slp+edgedensi+bps1*sclass1+vrm+(1 | ID), data=stdsuma, family=binomial, glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))
```

I am running a 5 fold cross validation to test the robustness of assumption of my best model using the formula

```
##Divide the data
k = 5 #Folds

# sample from 1 to k, nrow times (the number of observations in the data)
data$id <- sample(1:k, nrow(data), replace = TRUE)
list <- 1:k

# prediction and testset data frames that we add to with each iteration over
# the folds

prediction <- data.frame()
testsetCopy <- data.frame()

#Creating a progress bar to know the status of CV
progress.bar <- create_progress_bar("text")
progress.bar$init(k)


PTOT=NULL
for (i in 1:k)
  {
    # remove rows with id i from dataframe to create training set
    # select rows with id i to create test set
    trainingset <- subset(data, id %in% list[-i])
    testset <- subset(data, id %in% c(i))
  M1 <- glmer( UA ~ dem+cos+sin+slp+edgedensi+bps1*sclass1+vrm+(1 | ID),  data = trainingset, family=binomial, glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))

  P1=predict(M1, testset)
  names(P1)=NULL
  P1
  PTOT= c(PTOT, P1)
}
```

However, given that my location data are nested within each individual, I am worried that when I split the dataset randomly into 5 parts the location from the same individual is getting split and placed into different folds which will impact the prediction power of my validation.

To address this problem I have created a column based on the summer ranges my individuals  use (they are clustered in 5 different summer range within my study area)  and want to use one cluster as the test set and randomize the rest into four folds as training set and loop it over for each cluster.

P.S. link to data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/33u1lqav8v718ah/sum_active.csv?dl=0

Comment: I'm not seeing any creation or reference to an accessible dataset. This is happening so oftne that I am seriously question my posture of not downvoting when there is no MWE.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check this out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve